# MySQL delete data from a table

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, bigint

I have timestamp value in a column of my table.I need to keep all the data of the last week and delete rest data in the table(which is not belong to last 7 days).How can I do it?

The query that I tried is given below.

```
DELETE * FROM EmailMainTable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > 
DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 8 DAY);
```

**NOTE: My Filed Name is timestamp and i converted it to bigint**

My table's structure:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're converting the timestamps to varchars (using `date_format`), they will be compares **lexicographically**, which isn't the behavior you want. Just drop the formatting:

```
DELETE
FROM   EmailMainTable 
WHERE  `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY);
```

Comment: i got a empty set when i used this.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer for my own question.
This is the answer that worked for me.

```
DELETE 
FROM EmailMainTable
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000,"%Y-%m-%d") < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY);
```